# Using JDK that is bundled inside Android Studio as JAVA_HOME on Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, java, java-home

I tried to open Android Device Monitor and the Studio showed me this message =-O :
[image: need to install Java SE 6 runtime error]

It surprised me, because how have I been able to develop Android apps if I didn't have any Java installed?! Actually, Android Studio comes with bundled JDK/JRE (located in `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`), but it is not found by the system: executed `usr/libexec/java_home` gives

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
```

Setting `$JAVA_HOME` to `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home` did not help — `source .bash_profile` doesn't like that it's a directory.

QUESTION: I don't want to install new JDK if I already have one inside Android Studio. How do I set it as system default?

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Solution:

1. (**Updated 2023**) For Android Studio before Electric Eel 2022.1.1 and above: `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home`
2. MacOS versions before Big Sur: add line `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/` to `.bash_profile` file in your home directory. Run `source ~/.bash_profile` to update terminal.
3. Catalina, Big Sur, Mentere and above: add line `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home` to `.zshenv` file in your home directory. Run `source ~/.zshenv` to update terminal.

After that, running `java -version` gave this output and Java started to execute normally:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_112-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b06, mixed mode)
```

As for the Android Device Monitor — it still demands this ancient JRE version 6.

Comment: how to get keytool when using the OpenJDK? It says "To use the keytool command-line tool you need to install a JDK"

Comment: Also, after this Android Studio stopped freezing on startup

Comment: Very useful. You cannot download JDK 8 from Oracle's site without a user. Only the latest JDK, 12 at this time - which does not work with gradle 4.4.1 which i'm using for my project. It's a mess. Also homebrew has no JDK 8. This was the solution that worked, thank god for embedded JDK!

Comment: Though java -version works fine, /usr/libexec/java_home still fails for me after adding JAVA_HOME

Comment: Sweet. I didn't have to restart my mac.

Comment: This is perfect. The Android Studio Installer should have a choice to do this on installation. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, Literally for some magical reason, restarting the OS fixes this.

Comment: How to find the one n Win 10?

Comment: if you're using Catalina and above, you probably use a zsh shell by default. So instead of adding it to the bash profile, create a .zshrc file in the home directory. Then in Terminal type `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: @RaphaelPinel, thanks for the advice about Catalina and Big Sur. You may freely edit my answer. Or should I do it?

Comment: For zsh the following line (added to the ~/.zshrc file) worked for me: `export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/"`

Comment: I'm running Monterey and just installed Android Studio 2020.3.1. There was no `jdk` directory within `jre`. So, this is what worked for me: `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home`

Comment: setting it on .zshrc will be better. as it is the default source.

Comment: With the latest "Electric Eel" release, `/jre/` changed to `/jbr/`so it's now `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home`

Comment: for me with zsh and electric eel: ~/.zshrc -> export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/"

Answer (score 108):

## Updated 2023

I just did a fresh install of Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 on Big Sur, and I had to use the following.

Android Studio Dolphin and below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```

Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 and above:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
```

On a slightly different topic, even with the correct `JAVA_HOME`, I couldn't start `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager`. I had to install "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)" (from Android Studio) and use `~/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager` instead.

Comment: Thank you solamour, I also just fresh install Android Studio Arctic Fox on Big Sur.
And it work

Comment: "/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/" it's not working.

Comment: @NeluB, what is the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `which java`, and `java --version` on your machine? While you are at it, share the output of `ls -la /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/` as well.

Comment: I fixed this by creating a symbolic link from the JRE folder to a new JDK folder.
`cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre`
`ln -s ../jre jdk`. Then updating back the JAVA_HOME to `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`. Thanks to https://fluttercorner.com/flutter-unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-after-updated-android-studio-arctic-fox2020-3-1-on-m1-apple-silicon/

Comment: This worked for me; I needed to accept the license agreements, but the sdkmanager suggested by Android Studio did not work.   "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)" are installed from Preferences/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK, then "SDK Tools" tab, then check the box and click Apply.  To accept the licenses, run the "latest" tool with the --licenses flag

Comment: this is the answer I am looking for, thanks

Comment: Thanks, this is what tripped me up eventually. I was trying to setup Unreal Engine 5 on macos M1 using SetupAndroid.command and running zsh instead of bash. I ended up replacing all references to .bash_profile to .zprofile as well as hardcoding the full path to the /Users/<my user>/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager to get it to run.

Comment: Before I used the above path inside "" in .zshrc file, after removing the quotes it started working.


Old:
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home"

New:
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home

Comment: I think you should have "no quotes with backslash" OR "quotes without backslash". It most likely won't work if you have "quotes with backslash", because the backslash won't be recognized as the escape.

Answer (score 14):

The core problem is that starting from Android Studio Arctic Fox the destination of bundled java has been changed from:
`/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/`
to:
`/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/`

You just need to change JAVA_HOME env variable in `.bash_profile` to the new correct path (be careful with space character, easiest way just to specify path in doubled quotes). And either restart terminal or run `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I just need to close terminals and open new terminals to check.

Answer (score 12):

As pointed out by [dimezis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3286059/dimezis), JAVA_HOME might be working but the /user/libexec/java_home is still broken.

This is because in Mac, `java_home` and `JAVA_HOME` are different. `JAVA_HOME` is the environment variable / path that will be used in most applications and environment while `java_home` is the actual executable that is being used by the system to run java. Apparently, some Mac applications (like Xcode) will just ignore the `JAVA_HOME` path and make use of the `java_home` executable

So in order to use the Android Studio Embedded JDK as default Java to be used in Mac, copy the entire embedded jdk folder `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk` to the default Java library folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

After this, set your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` with this:
`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

This will make sure that your JAVA_HOME and java_home is pointing to the same java installation.

Comment: Yes thank you!!! Though rather than copying, it's probably better to just create a symlink
`sudo ln -s /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/android-studio.jdk` (this is the path for Android Studio Electric Eel. Check what's in your Android Studio app folder for the right path). Also, remove any other java installation you may already have in the JavaVirtualMachines folder.

Comment: Yes that would be better! :-)

Comment: This should be mark as the answer, thanks for detailed explanation. Not sure but in Windows I do not need to do all this stuff and didn't even need to specify JAVA_HOME. All I need is to put the JBR bin directory in %PATH% and everything will work such as keytool, jarsigner, etc.

Answer (score 6):

in my case escaping with `\`  doesn't work but escaping whole path with `"` works fine. Please reopen terminal to see changes or run `source ~/.zshenv` to update terminal.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/"
```

Comment: Just FYI: `java` bin located directly in the `*/bin` folder of the provided path.

Answer (score 5):

From late 2022+, the answer for Mac User & Electric Eel+ has been changed to:

> export JAVA_HOME=export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home

to .zshenv file in your home directory

Comment: That's the right export command, since in the latest Android Studio one of the folders  name changed from jre to jbr

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved my issue on MAC:

```
# Android, ADB and JAVA
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: Works on M1 in 2022

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Thanks. Worked in Mac M1

Comment: Worked for me, I just updated my Studio to Eletric Eel

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me (MacOs Ventura version 13.1)

1. Enter the following command in the command line

   `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home`
2. Create a new folder inside `Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents` and call it `jre`.
3. Copy the contents of `jbr` folder into the newly created folder`jre`.
4. Run `flutter doctor`.

Link : [flutter issues link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED 2024**

I'm using MacOs Sonoma and Android Studio Hedgehog. Here is how I solved it:

1. If you do not already have .zshrc file in your home then add it and if you already do have then open it using any text editor. ( Hint: .zshrc is hidden by default, so you might need to show hidden files to see it by pressing `command + Shift + .` )
2. Add `export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/"` to it and save it.
3. Close and re-open your terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc` in your terminal for changes to take effect.
4. Finally you can now run `Java -version` to confirm issue has been fixed.

Comment: Helped to solve issue with command line builds

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

- Got to finder and right click it and press ## Show packages content ##
- Got to Contents and create a new folder called jre
- inside jre copy the content of the jbr folder
- the flutter run

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Use the output path as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME="<path_you_received>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have three exports path in home/.zshrc mac system

1. jdk path
2. path Contains ordinary commands and shell scripts.
3. Android sdk path

   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home

   export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"

   export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk