# How to add and use Android Studio JRE or JBR in $PATH via symlink?

Tags: macos, unix, symlink

Coming from Windows, you can easily add Android Studio's JRE now JBR directory in environment variable path where executable such as jarsigner and keytool are located. I tried to do the same in macOS but using symlink as the suggested method I am seeing in the web.

First I copied the directory to my clipboard

```
/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin
```

Then followed this SO [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41586) and executed the below command

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin /usr/local/bin
```

I already echoed `$PATH` and found `usr/local/bin` so I skipped the mkdir part.
Unfortunately it does not work and seems broken.

This is what I am seeing

```
user@User-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -la /usr/local/bin/
total 354896
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel        288 Aug  9 02:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel        192 Aug  8 01:12 ..
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         21 Aug  9 02:31 Android -> /Applications/Android
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel          6 Aug  9 02:31 Studio -> Studio
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         42 Aug  9 02:31 bin -> Preview.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         45 Aug  8 02:39 corepack -> ../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  181706736 Jul 18 20:09 node
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         38 Aug  8 02:39 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         38 Aug  8 02:39 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

[image]

What went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You can't do `ln -s PATH WITH SPACES ...` You must do `ln -s "PATH WITH SPACES" ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks I will try that, also can I delete the broken symlinks using Finder app itself?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm pretty sure you should *not* do that -- the `npm` and `npx` symlinks are part of `node`, and should not be deleted.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS There's another problem here, and it means you can't use the symlink method. The symlink method tries to *replace* the normal /usr/local/bin directory with a symlink to the Android Studios bin directory, but you already have a real /usr/local/bin directory with `node` and *its* symlinks there; you'd have to remove the entire directory (thus breaking `node`) in order to replace it with a symlink to the Android Studios bin directory. So... pick a different method to add that directory to `PATH`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ok, thank you. I'll delete my suggestion right now.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I excluded Mark's suggestion of removing npm, npx, and those that I did not add manually only deleting those that I added. However I discovered that even running the keytool command in the actual bin directory it still failing with error `The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
`. I am not sure why it is not working since in Windows it works properly and I am expecting that Android Studio's JDK is already being use thus no need for me to install it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson does it mean doing that symlink in this case will not work at all? Thanks

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS It means that in order to make the symlink work, you'd need to delete part of your `node` setup. Essentially, with the symlink method, you can have Android Studios *or* `node`, but not both.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I can only symlink one which is node in this case?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS node isn't using a symlink, it's using an actual directory with files in it. This is the standard way to do things, and can coexist with lots of other things (as long as they *also* use the actual-directory-with-files system). The symlink method, on the other hand, is a nonstandard kluge which cannot coexist with anything else that needs /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for hours I finally got what I am looking for from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69235473)

First check if **java_home** is in **/usr/libexec**

Then check if **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines** directory exist

After confirming, get or copy the Android Studio JBR path in my case this is **/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jbr**

Noticed that there is spaces in path, what you can do is either add escape or just wrap the whole path with double quote.

**Be careful with the double quote " as copying from apps line Notes that has Smart Quote Substitution enabled, it will change your regular quotes to “ Left Double Quotation.**

Then you will have this command to create symlink instead of copy pasting it to JavaVirtualMachines folder.

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jbr" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Once success execute this command

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

You should now be able to run those commands that are available inside JRE or JBR bin such as **keytools** and **jarsigner** while also setting and fixing your JAVA_HOME setup.